# Label in Pine Script indicator

Tags: pine-script

I created a pinescript indicator that uses MACD. I want it to label a on chart when a certain condition met. Even overlay is set true it is still showing label in separate window with macd not on candlestick chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot work with two different `overlay` styles. If your MACD indicator's `overlay` is set to `false` it can only plot things on a separate pane.

You can have one script with `overlay=true` and do the calculations for MACD there without plotting any MACD lines. So, you would have the values anyways but not the visual representation. Then plot those values with a label.